# Spring hibernate get data based on other table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using spring & hibernate for a project. I have two tables in the database where `pid` column data is same in both of them.

Table Pt:

```
pid    pt_col1   pt_col2
1        ab        de
```

Table PDetails:

```
id    pDetails_pid    pDetails_col
1          1              y
```

Now, I want to get the data from Table `Pt` where `pDetails_col=y`.  I find 2 ways to do that. First is to do join, but joins are very time consuming. Second could be to do looping of `Pt` Table inside `PDetails` table like

```
this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().CreateQuery("Select pDetails_pid from PDetails WHERE pDetails_col=1")

while()
{
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().CreateQuery("Select * from Pt WHERE pid=" + pDetails_pid);
}
```

Is there any other better way to retrieve the data via hibernate?

Comment: With right foreign key index join works quite well. Have you measured the performance of a solution with join? `select p.* from pt p, pdetails d where p.pid = d.id`

Comment: HQL does not need 'SELECT' in case of all rows.. you can change your second query to "from Pt WHERE pid=" + pDetails_pid.
And you can add index on pid column

Comment: Why text of query does look like SQL? Do you really have entity `PDetails` with `pDetails_col` field?